# Panel Data including Subgroups or Pooled OLS

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am analysizing a dataset which is seperated by countries, but also in age groups and gender cohorts, 5 annual periods are included. An intervention took place inbetween the years.

As the data is sparse, I want to compare the effects of each subgroup , so I may reach statistic significance afterall (e.g. female between 10-20 years for both countries, this variable I will call ID, existing only one number per country).

1. I have tried panel analysis with the plm package, however, I have tried to index country, year, and ID, but this does not work as it is not unique.
   Is it even possible to include country effects but have subgroups of the country? (see code below)
2. I have tried Difference in differences, by using lmList and saving the coefficients. This for each subgroup seperated through the ID´s. (see code below)
   This has worked, but through limited periods, no statistic significance is reached, even though the coefficients are all same direction. So I wonder if there is a possibility of combining those models again, and by that reaching reliable results?

`1. fixed <- plm(FE ~ x  , data=df, index=c("ID","country", "year"), model="within")`

`2. list <- coef(lmList(y~ treated + time + did | ID, data=df))`

Error from 1.

```
  duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
2: In is.pbalanced.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :
  duplicate couples (id-time)
```

For 2.
I do get a dataframe which contains all coefficients, but any ideas how I could properly summerize or display those? Just taking the mean of a coefficient seems to be a bit low-skilled.

Answer (score 0):

I adress the first issue (just coding). `plm` requires a panel structure of `index=c("individual", "time")`. But you can define a new ID for whatever your unit of observation is. Here you can combine those numerical variables from your identifier with `dplyr`:

```
 library(dplyr) df <- transform(df,GID=paste0(ID,country))

 library(plm) summary(plm(y ~ x, index=c("GID", "year"), data = df,
 model = "within"))
```

In general, you can define all other kind of observational groups. Is your "ID" numeric or string? You should add a more detailed data description or give some example data.